# How many comparisons does insertion sort do in an already-ordered 2-element array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

The best case scenario of insertion sort is meant to be O(n), however, if you have 2 elements in an array that are already sorted, such as 10 and 11, doesn't it only make one comparison rather than 2?

Comment: `O(n)` doesn't mean `n`. It means linearly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity of **O(n)** does not mean that the number of steps is exactly **n**, it means that the number of steps is dominated by a linear function.  Basically, sorting twice as many elements should take at most twice as much time for large numbers.

The best case scenario for insert sort is when you can insert the new element after just one comparison.  This can happen in only 2 cases:

- You are inserting elements in from a reverse sorted list and you compare the new element with the first element of the target list.
- You are inserting elements from a sorted list and you compare the new element with the last one of the target list.

In these 2 cases, each new element is inserted after just one comparison, including in the case you mention.

The time complexity would be indeed **O(n)** for these very special cases.  You do not need such a favorable case for this complexity, the time complexity will be **O(n)** if there is a constant upper bound for the number of comparisons independent of the list length.

Note that it is a common optimization to try and handle sorted lists in an optimized way.  If the optimization mentioned in the second paragraph above is not implemented, sorting an already sorted list would be the worst case scenario, with `n` comparisons for the insertion of the `n+1`th element.

In the general case, insertion sort on lists has a time complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, but careful implementation can produce an optimal solution for already sorted lists.

Note that this is true for lists where inserting at any position has a constant cost, insertion sort on arrays does not have this property. It can still be optimized to handle these special cases, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort does `N - 1` comparisons if the input is already sorted.

This is because for every element it compares it with a previous element and does something if the order is not right (it is not important what it does now, because the order is always right). So you will do this `N - 1` times.

So it looks like you have to understand a [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Because `O(n)` does not mean `n` operations, it does not even mean close to n operations (`n/10^9` is O(n) and it is not really close to `n`). All it mean that the function approximately linear (think about it as limit where n-> inf).